# Duplicate dash on gnome panel

Tags: 20.04, gnome-panel, gnome-dash

I installed ubuntu 20.04 2 days ago, but yesterday I started having this weird bug where I get a duplicate dash.

It started happening more frequently. Usually when I log out and log back in it comes back to normal, and even if I simply ignore it, it usually comes back to normal as well.

I'm not sure if it's due to any changes I did on the dash? I simply disabled the extended option. I'm not really sure why this happens but it's frustrating.

Any help? Here's an image:

[image: duplicate dash]